# C: How to generate a fixed number of objects with an array of pointers

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I would like to create 11 text layers for a pebble watch face.
Without a loop the code would look something like.

```
static TextLayer *time_layer_a;
static TextLayer *time_layer_b;
```

... and so on.

How can I do this with a loop and put the pointers to the the objects in a *list* like structure?

*list*: in this case array or chain would be a better word because the collection of pointers is for a display with a fixed number of text layers. And the number of layers will not be changed during the duration of the program. In C, a list is a structure that can be dynamically resized. Using "list like" could mislead helpful people to the assumption that the sought method of chaining is expected to be dynamic. This is not correct. A structure that uses a fixed allocation of memory is preferred.

Edit: an array as suggested by John3136 worked perfectly. The array has the added benefit of generating the object pointers with its deceleration. And it's a plus that John3136 gave a way to have the code automatically adjust to the size of the array. This is a useful tool to have.

Here is the code as applied to create text layers for my watch face.

declarations:

```
int i;
static TextLayer* layers[11];
```

loading method:

```
// by John3136
// Note the sizeof() stuff means this works unchanged even if you change
// the number of layers.
for(i = 0; i < (short)(sizeof(layers) / sizeof(layers[0])); i++) // (short) converts unsigned interger to +- int
{
  layers[i] = text_layer_create(GRect((bounds.size.w/4)*((i + 1)%4), 
                                      (bounds.size.h/PBL_IF_ROUND_ELSE(5,4))*((i > 2) 
                                                                              ? ((i > 6) 
                                                                                 ? 3 
                                                                                 : 2 ) 
                                                                              : 1), 
                                      (bounds.size.w / 4) ,(bounds.size.h/PBL_IF_ROUND_ELSE(5,4))));
}
```

unloading method:

```
for(i = 0; i < (short)(sizeof(layers) / sizeof(layers[0])); i++) 
{
  text_layer_destroy(layers[i]); 
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Apparently you have some code already, so provide a [mcve]. Also learn [ask] and provide the necessary information.

Comment: Expanding this question to be a complete & compileable example would just add unnecessary clutter. I think this question is just fine as it is.

Comment: @Olaf, I am writing my first program in C. I do not yet know all the structures in C or what they are best suited to. I knew that I was looking for something that was "list like." At the time that was the best I could do. I would have asked for an array if I had known that an array would do work well.

Comment: Note: `sizeof` should not be casted to `short. It yields a `size_t` which you should use for your index, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way that meets your requirements as we know them: An array of 11 pointers to TextLayers.

```
static TextLayer*  layers[11];
```

You can then populate with:

```
int i;
// Note the sizeof() stuff means this works unchanged even if you change
// the number of layers.
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(layers) / sizeof(layers[0]); i++)
{
    layers[i] = some_func_that_creates_a_layer();
}
```

Comment: That's not a list, not evn list-like. It is not clear what OP really wants. MCVE missing.

Comment: @Olaf I agree with your point that we don't really know what OP wants (hence my first sentence). Having said that: In what way is a sequence of items not list-like? I think it's a reasonable chance that an array is a suitable solution which is why I posted as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: There is enough material to be found what constitutes a list (although there are variations, they have in common some kind of linking). There might be a particular reason OP asks about a list. Possibly because he wants to change it dynamically. Though I suspect he does not really know what he needs. Without more information, we have to work with what we got. If that is not enough, any answer is speculation and not really helpful for OP and possibly missleading for future readers. There is a reason for the "unclear" close-vote.

Comment: @Olaf i think we agree, but not on the details ;-) A linked list has linkage, but there are other types of lists (aka collections. Is a vector not list-like ?). Anyway. I suspect my answer is a good starting point for OP, so I'm leaving it here. Hopefully OP will edit the question, and if I'm wrong I'll delete (or edit).

Comment: That is a matter of implementation. Apparently OP asks about such an implementation. Notice that C does not provide vectors, etc. And no, I don't talk about linkage (that has a specific meaning in C context!). Maybe "chaining" would have been a better term. Anyway, an array per se is definitively not a list. Collections are another thing. I have the impression you confuse complex data structures and lists. Collections, lists and vectors are data structures. With some being potentially the basis for others.

Comment: @Olaf: OP never said what he wanted to do with the list. An array is the simplest way to solve the problem they wrote about, which is allocating storage for 11 different variables and being able to iterate over them with a loop.

Comment: @hugomg: Reading skills: "... in a list like structure?" - which definitively excludes arrays.

Comment: @hugomg: **Who** is being rude here?? Python does not have a built-in array type, nor does it state a list is the same as an array. It allows to access list elements by their position. But that does not make a list an array! Anyway, your offence disqualifies you for rationale discussion. You better mind your manners!

Comment: @John3136 thank you. An array satisfies what I meant by a list-like structure.